# How to grab recursive matches in groups?

Tags: php, regex

Imagine, I have the following string:

```
$str = "[block]teststring [block]teststring123  [/block][/block]";
```

I'd like to get the values in the [block] elements (`teststring`, `teststring123`). I know I could do sth. like:

```
<?php
$str = "[block]teststring [block]teststring123  [/block][/block]";

$regex = '/\[block\]([^\[\]]+)/';
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
// outputs array(array("[block]teststring ", "[block]teststring123  "),
//               array("teststring ", "teststring123  "));
?>
```

However, as I am learning more and more about regular expressions, I thought about using a recursion:

```
$regex = '/\[block\]([^\[\]]+)(?R)?/';
```

This works insofar as the whole string is matched, but then I am unable to access the submatches (`[block]teststring`, `[block]teststring123`). How can this be done via a regex in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this recursive regex:

```
\[block\]([^][]+)(?1)
```

`(?1)` recurses the 1st sub-pattern.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vE9pI3/1)

**Code:**

```
$re = '~\[block\]([^][]+)(?1)~'; 
$str = "[block]teststring [block]teststring123  [/block][/block]"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: What differs `(?1)` from `(?R)`? Also I seem to need escaped square brackets in my class.

Comment: `(?R)` recurses the entire pattern but `(?1)` recurses just the 1st sub-pattern.

Comment: In contrast I could not use `([^][]+)` (did not find any matches).

Comment: Yes as I said you can escape them as `([^\[\]]+)` [though `([^][]+)` works in this demo also](https://eval.in/485882)

Comment: Thanks a lot - love SO!